# Unauthorize apps from Google

Tags: google-authentication

I'm trying to un-authorize one of the apps that I've allowed previously to use my Google information.

Twitter and Facebook allows un-authorization. How do you achieve it in Google? Tried looking around the settings, but to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens is the URL to view/revoke permissions granted to third-party apps.

Answer (score 1):

If it's something you added to Google from the Chrome Store, go to the chrome store "your purchases" and click on the app you want to trash- there is a little trashcan icon to remove it from your profile:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/user/purchases

Answer (score 1):

You can also open your Google+ app, open settings, click on your name under account settings, and then click on apps with Google-plus signin.

Answer (score 0):

Jason's link worked fine, but https://myaccount.google.com/ seems less fragile. 
(Just scroll down to "Connected apps and services".)